# Tkinter canvas itemconfigure not text wrapping

Tags: python, tkinter, bind, tkinter-canvas

`Canvas.create_text` will not wrap text and keep it within the `canvas` widget as the window size changes. The `width` option will cause the line break to occur at a word but the behavior is completely unpredictable. Here is a sample of the problem I am having:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x350')
def change(event):
    print('event.width = '+str(event.width)) # Debugging
    canvas.itemconfigure(text_id, width=event.width)

canvas = Canvas(root,width=500,height=300)
text_id = canvas.create_text(250,50,text='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',anchor=N)
canvas.bind('<Configure>',change)
canvas.pack()

mainloop()
```

Using the `bind` event I've tried to change the `width` option of the `Canvas.create_text` method:

`canvas.itemconfigure(text_id, width=event.width)`

I've tried the `pack` method:

`self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True )`

I've tried the canvas.coords method:
`self.canvas.coords(self.total_prod_1_text,(text_x-400),50)`

Comment: The 'code' formatting is wrong. I don't want to try fixing it because I've caused a conflict in the past while it was being corrected by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the text to the width of the canvas, but centering the text at a fixed x coordinate of 250. If you want the text to remain centered in the visible area of the widget then you need to factor in whatever margin you expect on the left and right of the text, and also make sure that the center of the text is at the center of the visible canvas.

```
def change(event):
`enter code here`    margin = event.widget.coords(text_
    x = event.width/2
    y = event.widget.coords(text_id)[1]
    width = event.width - (2*margin)
    canvas.itemconfigure(text_id, width=width)
    canvas.coords(text_id, x, y)
```

Alternately, instead of fixing the top-center of the text, place the left part of the text at the left margin. Then, you don't have to reposition the text. You still have to account for the margin.

```
def change(event):
    coords = event.widget.coords(text_id)
    margin = coords[0]
    width = event.width - (2*margin)
    canvas.itemconfigure(text_id, width=width)
...
text_id = canvas.create_text(50,50,text='...',anchor=NW)
```

Comment: Bryan... this works perfectly. The flush-left option is exactly what I need. Getting the coordinates from the Text id and from that, setting up the margins is the big thing I was missing. The "NW" anchor causes the test to be justified left. Again, thanks.